# How to avoid default -webkit properties

Tags: html, css, webkit

when i'm running my code in chrome browser there appears some default `-webkit` properties.the problem is it is affecting the appearance of my web page,i would like to set that off .is it possible?.or there are any parallel solution?

[image: this is the problem i facing]

on this image you can see a gap between ash coloured part and green coloured part,that is the problem i'm facing...!.i idded the default webkit properties below.

[image: default webkit properties]

Comment: 1. you need to clear your *`float`*, 2. the *`shadow`* is being hidden due to  its upper and outer div positions.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `margin` will override `-webkit-margin-*`.

Chrome isn't doing much that's special here; most browsers will apply some default margin to `ul`.

Comment: in my case it does not make overriding,you can check that also.it's just take the modulus of both(wich means if webkit margin property is 8 and our margin property is -6,wich result in margin:2),so it will affect the responsive website.

Comment: when put <div> tag instead if <ul> i got what i requioreed,that is why i'm up voted..

Comment: Did you actually try to set the margin to 0 on the ul? That would have been the solution. Things like `-webkit-margin-start` are simply Chrome's way of expressing the margins in a direction-independent way. But they still are the _same_ margins!

Comment: Is the fact that your `margin-top` is disabled in the screenshot significant? It looks like you've either explicitly turned off that rule using the checkbox beside it in the inspector, or it has been commented out in your CSS. Either way, you need to enable it before it will have any effect :)